# X509Certificate2 - The remote server could not returned.(502) Bad Gateway

Tags: c#-4.0, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, system.net.httpwebrequest

I am passing ssl cerificate to client using httpwebrequest. I am getting below error. Here is the code.

```
string url = "htttps:\\localhost:1990\api";
string certpath = "C:\Sagar\certi.pfx";
Httpwebrequest req = (Httpwebrequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, password); 
req.ClientCertificate.Add(cert);
StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());

// this line raises exception "The remote server returned error: (502) bad Gateway."
sr.write(requestBody);
```

Comment: `htttps:` is it a typo in the post, or there is too much `t` letters?

Comment: It is typing mistake